# Is it possible to use an XAML UI in a C++ program?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I work on a 20 year old program which has alot of CDialogs inside. They are all called DoModal(). My users wish a more modern UI. In the past I have written C# apps with WPF and I wonder if I could add a new dialog into my old C++ program which is a XAML Dialog?

Alternativ:
I would like to seperate my current C++ program into 2 part: keeping the the logical part in C++ and redesign the Dialogs with XAML.

Is this directly possible?

Some time ago I had another project where I had a C# dll used in a C++ programm. Can I do it that way? How can I return the UI values and user actions to my C++ code then which has the logic about what to do with the inputs?

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest way would be to import `[DllImport]` C++ methods from a dll into a WPF application.

Comment: I can't change to a WPF C# Application because the old programm uses an old C API to communicate with an other program and an old database. It's something like a plugin.

Comment: I think you need to explain more about your app. EG  could this be made into a managed c++ project within a .net wpf solution?